# Background job with httpRequest failing

Tags: parse-platform

I'm running a background job with an httpRequest in Cloud Clode. I'm using the httpRequest code from the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html).

```
Parse.Cloud.job("test", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: 'http://www.parse.com/'
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    // success
    status.success(httpResponse.text);
  },function(httpResponse) {
    // error
    status.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
  });
});
```

This always returns failed in the job status in the dashboard. I thought I was over my concurrent job limit so I killed my other scheduled jobs, but it's still not working. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** When the job fails there is no message in the message column :(

Comment: I ended up converting my job to a function by using Parse.Cloud.define and running it as a function. You get better debugging messages to figure out what's wrong with your http request